# Why were the A-wings painted red at the Battle of Endor?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

We all know Alliance fighter squadron design: [image]

Red Squadron

[image]

Blue Squadron

[image]

Gold Squadron (although a little hard to see)

So why was "Green Squadron" colored like this in the movie?

[image]

I will accept both in and out of universe answers, but would prefer in-universe.

And, yes, it was "Green Squadron". The pilot was [Arvel Crynyd](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Arvel_Crynyd), and according to Wookieepedia:

> Arvel Crynyd was a male human pilot who served in the Alliance to Restore the Republic during the Galactic Civil War. In the war's fourth year, Commander Crynyd participated in the Rebellion's attack on the Galactic Empire's second Death Star in the Battle of Endor, flying an RZ-1 A-wing interceptor in Green Squadron as leader of the squadron.

Comment: Green squadron pilots wear green jumpsuits; https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/de/Arvel-crynyd.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120113223349 / https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/be/GreenLeaderTeralov.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20181230171829

Comment: The Rebels already had a Red Squadron in the battle and had better things to do than paint A-Wings a different color?

Comment: In Star Wars: Squadron, some of the Green Squadron A-Wings have little green stripes on them

Comment: @Null You're saying that they had time to paint every other ship, yet the one with a simple stripe down the middle they couldnt do?

Comment: No, I'm saying that they evidently didn't have any green-colored A-Wings on hand and declined to make the effort to paint some of them green for Green Squadron.

Comment: out of universe I think they are red because of green screen iirc

Comment: @NKCampbell That's why they changed Luke's X-wing squadron in the original film. It was Blue Squadron in earlier versions of the screenplay and in the novelization but the markings ruined the blue-screen effect for the models and so were changed to Red Squadron.

Comment: Their mechanic happened to be red-green colorblind, very embarrassing. But it was too late to repaint them before the battle so that's what they went with.